# Is it possible, that the get.weights command in Keras returns only rounded numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to construct a neural network, which i have previously trained in keras, in another program.
Therefore, i use the get.weights command from keras to acces the weights.
Now the problem is, that the results from the other program seem horrible so I am trying to figure out why.

Keras tells me, that the format of the weight is float32 and all the weights have a format looking like "5.30527434e-01" - which leads me to the conclusion, that keras is rounding the number. Is that correct?

And if it is, is there a way to access the full weights of the network?

Comment: Please explain how you see rounding in this value and what you mean by "full weights."  It looks like you might be confounding two senses of "format," by the way: "float32" apparently means an IEEE 32-bit floating point *internal* representation, while your second use of "format" seems to refer to a *decimal representation* used to *display* the number.  If anything, the number as displayed is *more* precise than its internal representation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get weights does give you the full weights. There is no reason why they would round them up, typically the size of a network is not the bottleneck, training speed is.

Comment: I found my mistake. I printed the weights with the python "print()" command. That was the point where the weights got rounded.